# How to select one of two formulas depending on a IF-expression in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: if-statement, libreoffice-calc

I want to implement something like that.

```
IF X < 1000 THEN
  Y = (1000-X) / 2 * 0.1 + 67
```

This doesn't work the way I expected.

```
=IF(A1 < 1000;(1000-A1)/2*0.1+67)
```

When `A1` is less then `1000` I get a `True` in the cell. If it is `1000` or more it is `False`.
What I want is the calculation should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple mistake.

The data type of the cell was set to "Boolean" by some stupid LibreOffice automechanism. Just set it back to "Number" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about LibreOffice, but this looks very similar to the setup for Microsoft excel functions.

=if(condition; *true output*; *false output*), i think the true and false outputs are optional. So, it must not be recognizing your true output statement. You also don't show a false output statement in your script.

try this,

=if(A1<1000; ((1000-A1)/2*0.1+0.67; 0)
and then just to be sure in a different cell,

=if(A1<1000; "output true", "output false")

the libre office api exmample page,

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions

shows a similar breakdown of the function call. It also has all the logical functions listed there as well. But I didn't see anything specific to addressing your issue.

try searching "libreoffice calc api if function"